# Problem with double tap on a website links on iOS

Tags: css, ios, hyperlink, frontend, touch

After 2 full days of trying out how to fix this, I am starting to give up. I am working on the website: https://www.lekm0.com which is using the wordpress theme Werkstatt by fuelthemes: https://werkstatt.fuelthemes.net/
they say that the double tap required on the menu, to open a link, is not a bug but a feature. After looking online it seems that this is the kind of implementation that is supposed to happen on iOS when you have a hover effect on a link with visibility or display.

Unfortunatly I don't want it since it seems a bit dumb to force people to double tap to open a link. I have deleted all the "hover" that I could find in the code but it is still happening on iphone and Ipad. No problem on Windows or Mac computer. Only on touch based screen like iphone or ipad.

If you any clue about this? thanks you!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so probably very dirty but it works :

```
<script>
jQuery(function(){
      jQuery('a').on('click', function (e) {
        if(jQuery(this).attr('href') !== '#' && typeof jQuery(this).attr('href') !== 'undefined' && !jQuery(this).closest('li').hasClass('menu-item-has-children')) {
          e.preventDefault();
          window.location.href = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        }
      });
    });
</script>
```

_ Makes the links in the menu to open on first clic,

Avoid the burger icon to reload the current page

avoid the link with submenu to load the link and open the submenu

drawback: apparently won't allow target blank links

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following post, your highlighted issue is addressed here.

https://css-tricks.com/annoying-mobile-double-tap-link-issue/

Comment: thank you for the link! I did seen it in my research unfortunatly it wasn't fixing my issue. Fortunatly after denying it for quite a while the theme editor provided a fix by modifying quite a lot of the JS they handle in the theme. Anyhow the fix below did fix (kind of) the issue as well. thank you for your help.? I am going to close the issue.

Comment: Thank you for the link. TL;DR`:hover` is typically ignored by most mobile/tablet browsers because of the inherent difficulty of handling it elegantly with only a finger tap's timing etc. Safari on iOS/iPadOS tries to actually handle the hover with initial taps. This kind of stinks so a proposed solution is to turn off hover CSS rules.